# how to do localization for iphone

Tags: iphone

i got button.... 
displays on button 
Search...

when i selected localization.....

i need to display

Zoeken

for search button its displays Zoeken...

@All thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you can write a better question than this... Next time, please try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`:

```
   NSString *buttonTitle = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"KEY", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"VISIBLE_DESCRIPTION", @"DEVELOPER_DESCRIPTION");
  [aButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlState...];
```

You'll then need to provide the relevant localization files in your project for the languages you intended on targeting.

Comment: Yes,,, In my configuration . I have down that.

Comment: You'll also want to provide the appropriate `.strings` file for each language.

Comment: Note that the fallback value cannot be an empty nsstring. In that case, the key is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As a top level skim, you can create per-locale NIB and string resource files using the built-in internationalisation capabilites.

However, this is quite a broad topic (there's an [entire section of the Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) dedicated entirely to internationalisation, complete with sample code, etc.), so what you need to do it read the documents there, look at the sample code and then ask a more targeted question if you get stuck/have a specific issue.